# How to change the default sort order in my opencart store to decreasing by stock_status_id?

Tags: sorting, opencart, product

i did these:

```
catalog/controller/product/category.php
```

i changed:

```
if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
            $sort = $this->request->get['sort'];
        } else {
            $sort = 'p.stock_status_id';
        }
```

In default when I refresh the page no action work just when I selected default choice I see this code `?sort=p.stock_status_id&order=DESC&limit=100` but not sort by `stock_status_id` yet!

Comment: in which file can i add stock_status_id to sort data?

Comment: also change this:
catalog/model/catalog/product.php 

        $sort_data = array(
            'pd.name',
            'p.model',
            'p.quantity',
            'p.price',
            'rating',
            'p.stock_status_id',
            'p.sort_order',
            'p.date_added'
        );

but still not work!!!

Comment: Do you want to sort products in category page by their stock quantity by default?

Comment: yes exactly,i want to sort it from exist product to out of stock

Comment: Which version of opencart?

Comment: Version 2.0.3.1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Open this file:

```
catalog/controller/product/category.php
```

find:

```
if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
    $sort = $this->request->get['sort'];
} else {
    $sort = 'p.sort_order';
}

if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
    $order = $this->request->get['order'];
} else {
    $order = 'ASC';
}
```

change it to:

```
if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
    $sort = $this->request->get['sort'];
} else {
    $sort = 'p.quantity';
}

if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
    $order = $this->request->get['order'];
} else {
    $order = 'DESC';
}
```